# How do I clear out core data after a specified period?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, uiviewcontroller, nstimer

I know how how to clear core data but I'd like to do is have it automatically cleared out after 60 minutes.

It's for a shopping cart. I'd like to give the customer a decent amount of time to make their order before the shopping cart is cleared. It is automatically cleared after a successful purchase. Now I need to take that same code that clears core data and have it run after 60 minutes no matter what.

How can I do this? Please show me an example.

I do know of the perform selector after duration method and I could possibly call this inside  the method I use to add items to the shopping cart. I'd call it only when the the carts total items is equal to 1 so it's only called once.

Maybe their is a better way to do this. Would like to see your iteads.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add timer which can clear the core data . See below code

```
 NSTimer * clearTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60*60 target:self selector:@selector(clearCoreData) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

make local variable if you have to use  timer other wise you can just write :

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60*60 target:self selector:@selector(clearCoreData) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and create the method for clearing core data.

```
-(void) clearCoreData {
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityName" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *items = _managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

   for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in items) {
     [_.managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
   }
   [_.managedObjectContext save:&error];
}
```

You  can also clear whole core data :

```
-(void)resetCoreData {
NSPersistentStore *store = ...;// core data NSPersistentStore object
NSError *error;
NSURL *storeURL = store.URL;
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *storeCoordinator = ...;// core data NSPersistentStoreCoordinator object            
[storeCoordinator removePersistentStore:store error:&error];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:storeURL.path error:&error];
}
```

Comment: ... with the standard caveat: be **very careful** about the potential for a context on a different thread having an object in use at the same time as you remove it from the persistent store. Exceptions lie that way.

Comment: What do I do with the unused clearTimer local var? Could I just call [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60*60 target:self selector:@selector(clearCoreData) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; in the method that adds items to the shopping cart?

Comment: Let's say I add another item to the bag and the timer code is run again. Is the timer restarted or is another one created?

Comment: @LondonGuy timer is scheduled . If local variable is just for using that timer . e.g. for invalidation if you need to do. Other wise you can write just [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60*60 target:self selector:@selector(clearCoreData) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

Comment: @LondonGuy it will not create another. it will restart after interval .